# Hello_World program using Python 3.10 gives me an error

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python.

I've created an easy print("Hello World") program using Sublime Text, and saved it as a .py file

I hit Tools/Build and gives me this error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\OscarZ\\Desktop\\python_work\\hello_world.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\OscarZ\Desktop\python_work]
```

```
[path:C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program 
   Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\OscarZ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps]
   [Finished]
```

Why doesn't it find the file? I'm opening it using the Sublime Text Editor

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed Python on your system?

Comment: It's not your script that cannot be found, it's Python itself - your editor is configured to use the `py` command to run the script, but I guess your Python installation requires a `python` or `python3` command.  (Or perhaps you simply don't have Python installed at all.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Python is installed. When I use the Python IDE, the program works fine. Also with the terminal. There's something wrong with Sublime Text :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use the 'Build System' of sublime to run your python codes, and you need to choose a build system by clicking 'Tools->Build With...' and selecting 'python' if you could see one.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that, and it still says it cannot find the specified file :(

Answer (score 0):

Write `python` in cmd, if the output shows a version of python, then python is fully installed,
If it show something else, go for reinstalling python from https://www.python.org/downloads/
If the python is installed correctly, try to run the same command in the IDE Python,
If the program runs perfectly there is some mistake or bug in the connection with the Sublime Text connection,
Try reestablishing the connection, or re installing the editor

Hope that works :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your kind words. Python works, also the IDE Python. The problem seems to be with Sublime Text, and I don't know how to fix it :(